# Send Email From Rest Component

Tags: rest, mule, mule-component

I have a requirement , where for one particular url , i need to send email . What should be the best approach of doing this ?

a ) Create a separate flow with vm inbound and add smtp connector there , call this vm endpoint from your Rest java component .

or

b ) create a choice filter after rest component , check the url and send email if it matches with the one , else send the original response .

I can not put choice filter before rest component because some rest interceptors are invoked and set some properties first , then only i need to prepare email content based on that .

Mule version is 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Is that URL dynamic? Did you consider using APIKit with RAML definition to expose your web service. If URL is not dynamic, then have a separate flow to handle it and generate email.

With VM approach, once message is pushed to VM or any other queue, it becomes asynchronous unless that's the behavior you want